# Separate server for Memcache/Redis?

Tags: django, redis, server, memcached, linode

I am using Django for my project and I ll be hosting it on Linode or any other hosting service. Plus if I want to use memcache will I require a new Linode for it? Means just one server will be ok or I ll have to host my site on 2 servers, one for memcache and one for django? And is it the same for Redis? Also will I require a separate server for Mysql?

Comment: memcached/redis can be on the same machine or a separate machine. It really depends on your use case. If you have an application with a small user base and only one linode instance, then memcache and your database can be all on the same machine. If you scale up to have multiple Django linode instances fed by a load balancer, then you need to decide whether you want each instance to have it's own local memcache or to all share a dedicated memcache, and your database will likely be on it's own machine as well.

Comment: @MarkGalloway: Lets say If someone is using memcache and MySQL along with django then is one instance of Linode enough? Can it be hosted on a single machine? No seperate need for MySQL and Memcache server?

Comment: It completely depends upon how much access your application receives and how resource intensive each request is. The only answer is profiling, unfortunately.

Comment: @MarkGalloway : Sorry I didn't get it. In case of my above comment will I be requiring different servers or a single one?

Comment: In the simplest case, for an application that does not receive many requests it is perfectly acceptable to put everything on the same machine. I don't know what you're developing or how popular it will be, so I cannot say. Start small and scale up with demand?

Comment: @MarkGalloway: I ll be having around 10k active users per month and it is sort of social so the no of feeds approx per month will be around 1m. Is it ok for single machine then?

Answer (score 9):

I don't think you understand that nobody is a fortune telling wizard. Nobody knows how many requests you will receive per second, nor how cpu/memory intensive each request will be. Nobody knows how optimized your code is. Nobody knows if your application is read heavy or write heavy. Your use case is your own, and your probably the only one who estimate it.

My only actual advice to you is to try to estimate your server data and sever load and benchmark your setup on one machine. If you are unsatisfied with the performance then scale up. You can either scale up vertically, by increasing the size of your linode, or scale horizontally by adding more linode instances. In the latter case, you will most likely put your DB on a machine of it's own and have multiple django instances fed by a load balancer. These Django instances could each share the same memcache on a machine, or they can each have their own memcaches on their own machine. Which one is better? I can't tell you. It again depends on your use case.

If I were you, I would set it all up on one linode instance. I would create test data that I assume would be close to real world. Then I would try to test my response times with an estimated number of requests per second. I would measure response times, cache hits, and memory usage. I would then decide based on that if *my use case* is satisfied with this level of performance or not because I'm really the only one who would know what is satisfactory performance. Additionally, adding more linode resources is not necessarily where I would first try and improve performance.

Some great tips on optimizing and benchmarking can be found here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/performance/
http://blog.disqus.com/post/62187806135/scaling-django-to-8-billion-page-views
http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/04/28/django-performance-testing-a-real-world-example/

Late night reading about scaling up Django can be found in many books, I like this one:
https://highperformancedjango.com/

Sorry if I sound a bit blunt, I just want you to understand that nobody can walk in here and give you an answer with a large degree of confidence. This question doesn't have a straight-forward answer.

TL;DR Start with one instance and scale up only if you've convinced yourself you need to.

Answer (score 4):

You say Memcached or Redis, so I assume Redis would be deployed without persistence, with a purely in-memory configuration.

In such case both Memcached and Redis are unlikely to get saturated even if you run them in one server, since the limiting factor is more likely to be a single Django instance if your requests/second go high.

However you should make sure to have enough memory and to configure an appropriate max memory usage for Memcached / Redis (different ways to accomplish this in the two different services). Note that under memory pressure, the Linux *OOM killer* may kill your cache otherwise, so if you go for a single instance, which seems to me a sensible first step, make sure your Django memory usage plus the memory you allocate for caching, are not enough to go near the limits of the instance free memory.

CPU is hardly going to be an issue as I said since Memcached / Redis are pretty good at using little CPU, so I can't foresee a setup where Django is ok serving pages but the instance is in trouble since the CPU is burned by the cache.

Comment: Okay! Means just one instance will be enough for less load?